# GNU GRUB 2.02 boot loop

Tags: 16.04, grub2, boot-repair

A year ago, I installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (32-bit) on my old Dell Latitude D820 notebook. Everything went well, till one day an automatic update arrived with a new version of GNU GRUB. This update started some booting problems.

After pressing the power on button, I see the Dell screen with F2 to enter BIOS etc. Short after that the GRUB menu appears. When I press Enter on the Ubuntu menu item, GRUB tries to boot the system, but then the screen goes black. After that the Dell screen and GRUB menu shows up again. This loop runs usually for a couple of times and finally GRUB can boot Ubuntu. What is the reason for this strange boot loop?

Comment: If Dell is reappearing, then it is totally rebooting. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Here is the boot info summary report of my Dell Latitude D820: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HkxXbWcDNj/

Comment: Additional Info: I’m using the disk encryption, that was activated during the installation of Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. The tool Boot-Repair suggests the encryption of the disc first, before proceeding with the automatic  repair, but I don’t understand what exactly is to be done. Do I need to completely uninstall encription first, like it is described in the section “How to Remove an Encrypted Private Directory Setup”? 

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory

Comment: For Boot-Repair to correctly see your encrypted partitions, you must mount those. So you have to give your passphrase to decrypt the LVM volumes.Then reinstall grub. It looks like you installed grub to partition boot sector originally, but now do have grub in MBR. BIOS based systems only boot from MBR.

Answer (score 1):

What I did so far:

```
sudo fdisk -lu

/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 468860927 467859458 223,1G  5 Erweiterte
/dev/sda5       1001472 468860927 467859456 223,1G 83 Linux

sudo pvscan 
PV /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt   VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [223,09 GiB / 44,00 MiB free]
Total: 1 [223,09 GiB] / in use: 1 [223,09 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

sudo vgscan 
Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2

sudo vgchange -a y
2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active

sudo lvscan 
ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/root' [219,81 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1' [3,24 GiB] inherit

sudo mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/root /mnt/mydisk
```

After mounting /dev/ubuntu-vg/root I started Boot Repair and clicked on the automatic repair. I got the same message to decrypt the partitions. I wonder, why I need to decrypt partitions and mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/root manually, if Ubuntu is running and everything is already decrypted?

Anyway, I proceeded with Boot Repair and installed GRUB in /dev/sda1.  Boot Repair gave me the message that the reinstallation was successful. The boot loop is still there though. Ubuntu will boot sometimes and sometimes will not.

Now I keep my notebook in stand by modus, because this way I can use it immediately instead of hoping that it is going to boot somehow if I’m lucky :-)

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VzwNCMtX9D/

Answer (score 1):

I found some interesting stuff the net. **Super Grub Disk 2** is a software, that makes it possible to boot totally messed up Linux systems that use GRUB2. This works also with encrypted volumes (Cryptosetup-Luks or Logical Volume Manager LVM). After downloading and burning the ISO-file, I started the computer from this CD. Ubuntu booted without any problems, so I think that there is no hardware failure that causes the boot loop problems.

https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/

The recommendation is to run the command:

```
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/[hard disk] update-grub
```

So I entered:

```
sudo fdisk -lu

Gerät      Boot   Start      Ende  Sektoren Größe Id Typ
/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 468860927 467859458 223,1G  5 Erweiterte
/dev/sda5       1001472 468860927 467859456 223,1G 83 Linux


sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda update-grub
grub-install: Error: More then one installation device?

sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda1 update-grub
grub-install: Error: More then one installation device?
```

Now the questions is, what does grub-install mean by “more then one installation device?”. I have only one hard disk with Ubunu only on it installed? What are the other installation devices supposed to be?

Comment: `grub-install --recheck /dev/[hard disk] update-grub` is not a valid command,  I think it was meant to run two commands, first `grub-install --recheck /dev/[hard disk]` and then `update-grub`.

Comment: You are right, these are to separate commands. Nevertheless they don’t help in my case. The strange boot loop is still there.

Answer (score 1):

A good workaround for now is to install the rescue software **Super Grub Disk 2** on a small USB stick that sits permanent in the USB slot of the computer. There is a software *YUMI – Your Universal Multiboot Installer* that can install the `super_grub2_disk_hybrid_2.02s10.iso` on a USB stick. Ubuntu boots from the rescue USB stick, decrypts the LVM volume and works just fine.

The Master Boot Record MBR on the hard drive is still messed up by the automatic Ubuntu GRUB 2.02 update, but with the rescue USB stick it does not matter that much any more.

Besides, GNU Grub 2.02 is still considered bata, so problems in some special cases are to be expected by definition.

https://www.supergrubdisk.org/wizard-step-put-super-grub2-disk-into-a-media/